# Make an WD partition bootable with kali linux?

Tags: kali-linux, macintosh, macos

I have a 512 GB passport SSD and it is partitioned to 2 partitions. One is 50 GB and the other is 462 GB, both of them are formatted exFAT. I want to take the 50 GB partition and make it a bootable partition of Kali Linux live with persistence.

I tried using Rufus but it only shows the whole SSD as a selection not each partition. I tried formatting this partition to FAT32 and copied the content of the ISO to it but it didn’t appear in the boot menu.

PS: I have a MacBook Pro 2018

Comment: You need to have your hard drive unformatted. If you are on macOS you can use `dd` to write the ISO to the drive and then you can take the remaining space and format that for use for the live boot with persistence. The Kali Linux site has all the [documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence/) to complete this task.

Comment: How do i unformat the drive and what’s the full dd comand

Comment: you can just `dd if=name-of-kali.iso of=/dev/sdX` where x is your flash drive or external hard drive, etc. This will unformat the drive and effectively destroy whatever files are on it so make sure that you are doing this to the right drive. You may need to do something special with your Macbook to get it to boot anything other than macOS since that appears to be a model with the T2 secure boot chip. I have no clue what this would be as I don't own a 2018 Macbook Pro and have never used one.

Comment: when I do the dd command it says operation not permitted

sudo dd if=/Users/jino/Desktop/kali-linux-2020-1-live-amd64-iso/kali-linux-2020.1-live-amd64.iso of=/dev/sddisk2s2
dd: /dev/sddisk2s2: Operation not permitted

Comment: Have you given your terminal app full disk access permissions?

Comment: How do i do this

Comment: I’ve given the terminal full disk access from security and privacy in system preferences but still the operation is not permitted

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

`dd`'ing the Kali ISO image to a partition may not work, because if the ISO image has been prepared for use on non-CD drives also, it already contains a partition table: you'll need to `dd` it into the whole-disk device (`/dev/sddisk2`).

Once you've done that, you should be able to use partition management tools to make the unused space available as an ExFAT partition.

Note that if you want Kali to be bootable *on a modern Mac* that uses UEFI, one partition for Kali is not going to be enough: you will also need a small ESP (EFI System Partition) that will contain Kali's bootloader. The ESP filesystem type must be FAT32 (or specifically on Macs, HFS will also work): ExFAT will not work unless Apple has added specific UEFI boot support for it. All this will probably be done automatically for you if you write the Kali image into the whole-disk device. This is probably also why Rufus is not giving you the option to write just into a specific partition.

And yes, what you see when accessing the image as an ISO9660 filesystem may be different from how it looks like when written onto a non-CD disk device.

If the partition is mounted, then the operating system might not allow `dd` to overwrite the partition/disk.

Before you can boot Kali on your Mac, you probably need to go into MacOS Recovery and use the Startup Security Utility to set it to "No Security" and "Allow booting from external media". See this Apple document: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330

The Kali ISO image has gone through a special `isohybrid` process and has an embedded partition table which will become active if the ISO is written to a whole disk.

Your plan of extracting the contents of the ISO to a partition would require first partitioning the SSD to include at least the ESP + Kali partition + any other partitions you wish it to have, then manually copy the contents of the ISO so that the bootloader parts go to the ESP and the rest to the Kali partition. In this process, the embedded partition table in the ISO would not be used at all.

Knowing the exact requirements here is the hard part, and it happens *before* you even boot to the SSD. You may have to set the name/UUID of the Kali partition exactly to the values the Kali installer will expect and recognize, and you would probably have to reverse engineer the Kali live media process to find those requirements, as I don't think they are documented anywhere.

Even if you manage to get it booting and recognizing your SSD as a valid Kali live media, I don't know if the standard process for setting up persistence will work if there are already extra partitions on the SSD. You might have to skip the automation and do the equivalent things manually on the command line. And I don't know what those things would need to be: you might be trying to do something completely new here.

**It would probably be much easier to just use the standard procedure to install Kali on your SSD (initially using the whole SSD), boot into Kali to set up persistence, then boot to some other OS (e.g. MacOS) and shrink the Kali live-with-persistence partition(s) to allow for creation of whatever other things you plan adding to the SSD.**

Comment: Could you please tell me the steps of installation once i boot to the ssd, cause things got confusing and i couldn’t do it since i think i need to do manual partitioning to make the ESP

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Kali well enough to give you exact steps. Please see my edit above.